# Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparison with COUNT

Tags: tableau-api

I know this is very commom question. But I havenot still known why in my case as follows. Give me your idea about this issue:
Question: I want to count the number of user who appear in list < 3. 
- First I created the "calculated Field" 
- Here is my function:

```
If COUNT([User]) < 3 then [User] END
```

Finally, I count this Meseasure again to gain the final result. 
Here's my example:

```
User
a
a
a
a
b
b
c
b
```

The result expected: **1** (only c) 
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your IF statement inside the COUNT().

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer help me in another case as well.